# PHP: Included function versus call to a static function. Is one better than the other?

Tags: php

I have a message class that I use like so:

```
RedirectMsg::go('somepage.php', MessageType::ERROR, 'Your message here.');
```

Would it be better to use a regular function? Or is this a personal preference issue?

```
redirectMsg('somepage.php', MessageType::ERROR, 'Your message here.');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Objects</strike> Classes help provide a <strike>sudo</strike> pseudo-namespace for functions so that they don't overlap, which can be very helpful. Have a large number of functions in the global namespace is a naming disaster waiting to happen. If you're using PHP 5.3 you might want to look into [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Comment: I'd love to have a `sudo namespace` command! In the meantime, you probably mean "pseudo". ;-)

Comment: Thanks Kendall. I think this is wise.

Comment: @deceze `sudo` make me a namespace

Comment: "Objects help provide..." - no objects involved here. Should be "Classes".

Answer (score 0):

This is generally a personal preference thing. It also depends on the scope of your application. You can afford to "organize" less in a smaller app and just save yourself the typing.

Comment: I personally prefer just to have it as simple functions, however many PHP frameworks (for example) use the static method way.